# How to add data from XML file to MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file called categories.xml. Here is a sample of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
<category>
<filter>julyfourth</filter>
<name>4th Of July</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>accessories</filter>
<name>Accessories</name>
</category>
.
.
.
```

For each category I need to add its data to the tblCategories table. How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you even look for an answer
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Comment: What other sort of XML is there?